# how to place the values in get from my loop into an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I  have this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < friendslocations.length(); i++) 
{
    JSONObject c = friendslocations.getJSONObject(i);

    String friendName = c.getString(TAG_FRIENDNAME);
    System.out.println("friend name " + friendName);

    String friendLocation = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
    System.out.println("friendlocation" + friendLocation);
}
```

where it keeps printing me the values i want.

But I need to know how to place the values that come out from this loop (the friendname and the friendloaction ) in an array list where each index contains this (friendname, friendlocation).

So how can i do this?

Comment: you just asked this question 10 minutes ago.  Start by creating an array. then in the loop add the items to the array.

Comment: if you want keep two field with each other create one class and then create one `Arraylist` of the class

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your two attributes in a new Object and push that object into the arraylist.

```
class FriendData {
    public String friendName;
    public String friendLocation
    public FriendData(String friendName, String friendLocation) {
        this.friendName=friendName;
        this.friendLocation=friendLocation;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "friendName="+friendName+" friendLocation="+friendLocation;
    }
}

List<FriendData> friendsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < friendslocations.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = friendslocations.getJSONObject(i);
    String friendName = c.getString(TAG_FRIENDNAME);
    String friendLocation = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
    friendsList.add(new FriendData(friendName, friendLocation));
}
```

Comment: You probably should set your attribute values in the constructor if you are going to take them as parameters